# vue bootstrapTable cannot click v-on:click

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i cannot click `v-on:click` after mounted `.bootstrapTable()`
but not used `.bootstrapTable()` it is normal to use v-on:click

Do I need to listen to any additional functions?
Or what kind of code should I write?

**file.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="(d, index) in data" :key="index">
          <td><a class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" @click="callText(d.text)">{{d.text}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'file',
    data () {
      return {
        data: [{"text":'1'},{"text":'2'},{"text":'3'}]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      buildTable() {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({})
      },
      callText(t){
        console.log(t);
      }
    },
    mounted: function(){
       this.buildTable();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, and it still works. Are you even looking at your console? The only problem is that the cursor is not changing to a pointer as with an actual button.